# std::is_pointer of dereferenced double pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, static-assert, double-pointer

I have some code where i want to check for (accidental) double pointers in `static_assert`

```
#include<type_traits>


int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    float* arr[10];
    float ** pp;

    static_assert(!is_pointer<decltype(*arr)>::value, "double pointer detected");
    static_assert(!is_pointer<decltype(*pp)>::value, "double pointer detected");

}
```

I am curious why this compiles, as i was expecting the static_asserts to give an error.

Comment: Probably because dereferencing gives you a reference to the thing.  Most likely you need to strip that reference off the type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of those decltypes resolve to reference types, and therefore neither are pointers, and hence the static assertions pass. These would also pass:

```
static_assert(std::is_pointer<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*arr)>>::value);
static_assert(std::is_pointer<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*pp)>>::value);
```